# Running react-native run-ios command is stuck and giving black screen in simulator using Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator, xcode14

I have a react-native application that was running the iOS simulator perfectly fine before the Xcode was updated to 14.2. After the update, I tried to run the iOS build using `react-native run-ios` command but was only able to get the black screen in the iPhone simulator, and in the terminal, the process was stuck at the `info Launching "MY_APP_ID"` step. I tried the below solutions but nothing worked.

- Restarted the mac.
- Deleted the application's derived data.
- Deleted the XCode cache.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't download the XCode from the app store but from https://xcodereleases.com/. Even if you had downloaded the dmg from somewhere else, there is a chance of getting the issue.

**Fix:**

***I have deleted it and downloaded it again from the App Store***. The issue is fixed and I can see the app is being launched instead of a black screen.